# Change the response output format in XML and JSON only for webHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I've been working on this problem for quite a long time, here are my findings and requirements:

We have two endpoints:

- TCP endpoint
- WebHttp endpoint

Through the WebHttp endpoint, we need to support JSON and XML but with a custom response format. This is the format needed (only JSON shown for clarity):

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data" : {}
}
```

What we need is for each object returned to be serialized normally and be put under data in the hierarchy. Let's say we have this `OperationContract`:

```
ObjectToBeReturned test();
```

and `ObjectToBeReturned` is:

```
[DataContract]
class ObjectToBeReturned {
    [DataMember]
    public string A {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string B {get; set;}
}
```

Now, we would like through `TCP` to exchange directly the `ObjectToBeReturned` object but through `WebHttp` to have the following format as a response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "A": "atest",
        "B": "btest"
    }
}
```

**Possibility 1**

We have considered two possibilities. The first one would be to have an object say named Response that would be the return object of all our `OperationContract` and it would contain the following:

```
[DataContract]
class Response<T> {
    [DataMember]
    public string Status {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public T Data {get; set;}
}
```

The problem with that is we would be required to exchange this object also through the TCP protocol but that is not our ideal scenario.

**Possibility 2**

We have tried to add a custom `EndpointBehavior` with a custom `IDispatchMessageFormatter` that would only be present for the `WebHttp` endpoint.

In this class, we implemented the following method:

```
 public Message SerializeReply(
            MessageVersion messageVersion,
            object[] parameters,
            object result)
        {

            var clientAcceptType = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Accept;

            Type type = result.GetType();

            var genericResponseType = typeof(Response<>);
            var specificResponseType = genericResponseType.MakeGenericType(result.GetType());
            var response = Activator.CreateInstance(specificResponseType, result);

            Message message;
            WebBodyFormatMessageProperty webBodyFormatMessageProperty;


            if (clientAcceptType == "application/json")
            {
                message = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "", response, new DataContractJsonSerializer(specificResponseType));
                webBodyFormatMessageProperty = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);

            }
            else
            {
                message = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "", response, new DataContractSerializer(specificResponseType));
                webBodyFormatMessageProperty = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Xml);

            }

            var responseMessageProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty
            {
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
            };

            message.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, responseMessageProperty);

            message.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, webBodyFormatMessageProperty); 
            return message;
        }
```

This seems really promising. The problem with that method is that when serializing with the `DataContractSerializer` we get the following error:

> Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using
>   DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the
>   list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

We really don't want to list all of our known types above our Response class since there will be too many and maintenance will be a nightmare (when we listed the knowntypes we were able to get the data). Please note that all the objects passed to response will be decorated with a `DataContract` attribute.

I have to mention that we don't care if changing the message format can cause the `WebHttp` endpoint to not be accessible via a `ServiceReference` in another C# project, they should use `TCP` for that.

**Questions**

Basically, we only want to customize the return format for WebHttp so, the questions are:

- Is there an easier way to accomplish that than what we are doing?
- Is there a way to tell the serializer the knowntype from the `result` parameter's type in the `SerializeReply` method?
- Should we implement a custom `Serializer` that will be called in the `MessageDispatcherFormatter` that will tweak the format to fit ours ?

We feel we are on the right path but some parts are missing.

Comment: KnownTypeAttribute can also be used with a method that returns all known types instead of a static list. Perhaps this is an option for you if you can collect all necessary types (for example via reflection) at runtime. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I was able to accomplish what I wanted. May not be the perfect solution but is working well in my case.

Possibility #2 was the way to go. But I had to change it to this:

```
 public Message SerializeReply(
            MessageVersion messageVersion,
            object[] parameters,
            object result)
        {
            // In this sample we defined our operations as OneWay, therefore, this method
            // will not get invoked.



            var clientAcceptType = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Accept;

            Type type = result.GetType();

            var genericResponseType = typeof(Response<>);
            var specificResponseType = genericResponseType.MakeGenericType(result.GetType());
            var response = Activator.CreateInstance(specificResponseType, result);

            Message message;
            WebBodyFormatMessageProperty webBodyFormatMessageProperty;


            if (clientAcceptType == "application/json")
            {
                message = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "", response, new DataContractJsonSerializer(specificResponseType));
                webBodyFormatMessageProperty = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);

            }
            else
            {
                message = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "", response, new DataContractSerializer(specificResponseType));
                webBodyFormatMessageProperty = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Xml);

            }

            var responseMessageProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty
            {
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
            };

            message.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, responseMessageProperty);

            message.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, webBodyFormatMessageProperty); 
            return message;
        }
```

The key here was that since Response is a generic Type, WCF needs to know all the known types and listing them by hand wasn't a possibility. I decided that all my return types would implement a custom IDataContract class (yes, empty):

```
public interface IDataContract
{

}
```

Then, what I did in Response, is to implement a`GetKnownTypes` method and in it, loop through all the classes implementing the IDataContract in the Assembly and return them in an Array. Here's my Response object:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ResponseOf{0}")]
    [KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
    public class Response<T>
        where T : class
    {

        public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
        {
            var type = typeof(IDataContract);
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));

            return types.ToArray();
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "status")]
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "data")]
        public object Data { get; set; }

        public Response()
        {
            ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.Success;
        }

        public Response(T data) : base()
        {
            Data = data;            
        }
    }
```

This allowed me to connect through TCP and exchange objects directly and have a great serialization via WebHTTP in either JSON or XML.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost in the right track - having an endpoint behavior that applies only to the JSON endpoint is surely the way to go. You can, however, use a message inspector, which is a little simpler that a formatter. On the inspector, you can take the existing response, if it is a JSON response, and wrap the content with your wrapping object.

Notice that the WCF innards are all XML-based, so you will need to use the [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx), but that's not too complicated.

The code below shows an implementation for this scenario.

```
public class StackOverflow_36918281
{
    [DataContract] public class ObjectToBeReturned
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string A { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        ObjectToBeReturned Test();
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public ObjectToBeReturned Test()
        {
            return new ObjectToBeReturned { A = "atest", B = "btest" };
        }
    }
    public class MyJsonWrapperInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            object propValue;
            if (reply.Properties.TryGetValue(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, out propValue) &&
                ((WebBodyFormatMessageProperty)propValue).Format == WebContentFormat.Json)
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
                var newRoot = doc.CreateElement("root");
                SetTypeAttribute(doc, newRoot, "object");

                var status = doc.CreateElement("status");
                SetTypeAttribute(doc, status, "string");
                status.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("success"));
                newRoot.AppendChild(status);

                var newData = doc.CreateElement("data");
                SetTypeAttribute(doc, newData, "object");
                newRoot.AppendChild(newData);

                var data = doc.DocumentElement;
                var toCopy = new List<XmlNode>();
                foreach (XmlNode child in data.ChildNodes)
                {
                    toCopy.Add(child);
                }

                foreach (var child in toCopy)
                {
                    newData.AppendChild(child);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(newRoot.OuterXml);

                var newReply = Message.CreateMessage(reply.Version, reply.Headers.Action, new XmlNodeReader(newRoot));
                foreach (var propName in reply.Properties.Keys)
                {
                    newReply.Properties.Add(propName, reply.Properties[propName]);
                }

                reply = newReply;
            }
        }

        private void SetTypeAttribute(XmlDocument doc, XmlElement element, string value)
        {
            var attr = element.Attributes["type"];
            if (attr == null)
            {
                attr = doc.CreateAttribute("type");
                attr.Value = value;
                element.Attributes.Append(attr);
            }
            else
            {
                attr.Value = value;
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        string baseAddressTcp = "net.tcp://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8888/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress), new Uri(baseAddressTcp));
        var ep1 = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new NetTcpBinding(), "");
        var ep2 = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        ep2.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        ep2.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new MyJsonWrapperInspector());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        Console.WriteLine("TCP:");
        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddressTcp));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Test());
        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Web:");
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Test"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```